# How to compile template string at build time using Babel (not Webpack)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am using Babel (without Webpack) to transpile some ES6 code. The code contains a template literal which I would like to evaluate at build time.

The code contains the following import where I would like to inject the version:

```js
const Component = React.lazy(() => import(`projectVersion${__VERSION__}/FooBar`))
```

I have used a number of different plugins to try and achieve this such as `babel-plugin-inline-replace-variables`, `babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables`, but the code compiles to something like this:

```js
var Component = /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.lazy(function () {
  return Promise.resolve("projectVersion".concat("1", "/FooBar")).then(function (s) {
    return _interopRequireWildcard(require(s));
  });
});
```

But what I'm after is something along the lines of this (as if I just manually added the version to `projectVersion`):

```js
const Component = /* #__PURE__*/_react.default.lazy(() => Promise.resolve().then(() => _interopRequireWildcard(require('projectVersion1/FooBar'))))
```

One of the reasons for this is because when running the code with `concat`, I get the error `Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`.

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

---

**More Information**

Command: `babel src --out-dir build`

Babel Config:

```
module.exports = api => {
  api.cache(true)

  return {
    presets: [
      ['@babel/preset-env', {
        corejs: 3,
        targets: '> 0.25%, not dead',
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
      }],
      ['@babel/preset-react', {
        runtime: 'automatic',
      }],
      '@babel/preset-typescript',
    ],
    plugins: [],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having tried many different potential solutions, I eventually landed on writing a custom babel plugin to replace the `TemplateLiteral` with a `StringLiteral`.

The code below is written quite lazily and is specific for my use-case, but hopefully it will help someone. If I have time, I will make it more robust and re-useable and share it on npm.

```js
module.exports = ({ types: t }) => ({
  visitor: {
    TemplateLiteral(path, state) {
      const { version } = state.opts

      const { expressions, quasis } = path.node
      const expressionStrings = expressions.map(exp => exp.name)

      if (expressionStrings.length === 1 && expressionStrings.includes('__VERSION__')) {
        const startString = quasis.find(q => q.tail === false).value.raw
        const endString = quasis.find(q => q.tail === true).value.raw

        path.replaceWith(
          t.StringLiteral(`${startString}${version}${endString}`),
        )
      }
    },
  },
})
```

Using the plugin is as simple as adding it to your babel plugins:

```js
plugins: [
  ['./babel/interpolate-template-literal', {
    version: "99",
  }],
],
```